# Increase val_acc in the audio classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have 530 data points belonging to 10 classes. I am not sure which numbers should I use for the `num_rows` and `num_columns`.

In this code I have `num_rows = 40`, `num_columns = 174`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001),  activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
# Compile the model
#opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=\['accuracy'\], optimizer="Adam")
```

[image: model loss]

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you have some sort of spectrograms on your input (since you're working with audio, but have 3-dimensional shape on input). Your `input_shape` has to reflect the size of images that you pass on input. Simply check their width and height - these are your `num_rows` and `num_columns`.

According to that code, the images have 3 colour bands. That makes sense for photos, but rarely for spectrograms. Remember these are false colours that typically are generated to create visually-pleasing visualisations, but don't get you anything when doing classification. Single channel is enough, the pixel intensity reflects strength (amplitude) of the signal.

Three simple things you can do:

- Use monochromatic images, e.g. `input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, 1)`. Colour only confuses the classifier.
- Get more data and use augmentation.
- `kernel_size=2` makes little sense. Read on convolutions first and what are the kernels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am writting the code and parallelly I am reading about cnn.Then it is better I will finish reading, then I will check the code.

Comment: @John Good luck. If the answer helped you, consider accepting it.

Comment: I want, but there is written that, I should have at least 15 reputation

Comment: One equestion more, how may I get the num_columns and num_rows for audio?

Comment: @John Audio is typically represented as a univariate time series (for mono) or multivariate (for stereo). For these number of columns or rows do not make any sense. A single data point tells you the sound pressure measured at discrete intervals. You need to have many of them so that you can interpolate the sound wave. Number of columns and rows (or rather: height and width) are relevant for spectrograms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram AFAIK there's no rep threshold to accept answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @John I am glad to hear that. Now, if you could just accept the answer by clicking on a green tick next to the answer...